# How to disable seqeval label formatting for POS-tagging

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, pos-tagger, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to evaluate my POS-tagger using huggingface's implementation of the `seqeval` metric but, since my tags are not made for NER, they are not formatted the way the library expects them. Consequently, when I try to read the results of my classification report, the labels for class-specific results consistently lack the first character (the last if I pass `suffix=True`).

Is there a way to disable entity recognition in labels or do I have to pass all my labels with a starting space to solve this issue? (Given that the library is supposed to be suitable for POS-tagging, I hope there is a built-in solution)

#### SSCCE:

```py
from seqeval.metrics import accuracy_score
from seqeval.metrics import classification_report
from seqeval.metrics import f1_score

y_true = [['INT', 'PRO', 'PRO', 'VER:pres'], ['ADV', 'PRP', 'PRP', 'ADV']]
y_pred = [['INT', 'PRO', 'PRO', 'VER:pres'], ['ADV', 'PRP', 'PRP', 'ADV']]

print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

#### Output:

|  | precision | recall | f1-score | support |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DV | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 2 |
| ER:pres | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1 |
| NT | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1 |
| RO | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1 |
| RP | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1 |
| micro avg | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 6 |
| macro avg | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 6 |
| weighted avg | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 6 |